# How do I suppress PowerShell cmdlet (Move-VM) results?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm writing a PowerShell script to sequentially move VMs off of a specified host and onto other cluster hosts using Live Migration.

The operative command is Move-VM (or Move-SCVirtualMachine), which is part of the VirtualMachineManager module. However, when I run this cmdlet, it always returns results to the console, which I want to suppress. I don't want to lose the information that the command returns.

The commands

`Move-VM -VM $vmToMigrate -VMHost $destinationHost`

and `$move = (Move-VM -VM $vmToMigrate -VMHost $destinationHost)`

will both return information to the console whether the result of the command is success or failure. My script incorporates logic on how to proceed depending on the results stored in `$move`, so I want the results of `Move-VM`, I just don't want them echoing to the console. I have tried

`($move = (Move-VM -VM $vmToMigrate -VMHost $destinationHost)) | out-null`

but none of the information returned by `Move-VM` is captured; the value of `$move` is null.

What's the best way of storing the results returned by `Move-VM`, without completely discarding what the cmdlet returns, while suppressing its output to the console? I want to avoid having my script output [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMCW7.png).

Thanks!!

**Updates:**

1. I have tried using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or setting `$ErrorActionPreference`, but if there is an error, then no output is stored to `$move`. I'd still want the output of `Move-VM`, so I can examine `$move` and execute different logic based on different types of failures.
2. I realize that I am essentially trying to accomplish what VMM's Maintenance Mode does (evacuate all VMs from a host and migrate them elsewhere in the cluster). However, VMM 2012 SP1 attempts to migrate multiple VMs at a time to/from Server 2008R2 hosts, which can't support more that 1 in & 1 out migration at once. Thusly, the migrations fail, and VMM will try to re-execute another group of migrations. Essentially, VMM gets stuck in a failure loop. The script avoids that by programmatically only migrating one VM at a time.

Comment: 2 questions: you don't want "1/17..." and "vms remaining.." or you don't want the error(because that's solved by using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. : )  Also, can I ask why you can't have the output? status-updates don't hurt when it's taking a while, and if you run it from a shortcut on the desktop or as a scheduled task, you won't see it when it's done anyways.

Comment: Hi Graimer, I don't want the red error output. The white text is only what I want printed to the console. I should've mentioned that I tried `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, but the problem is that `$move` is null if there is an error. I would like to be able to examine `$move` if there is a failure and run logic depending on the type of failure.

Comment: When I look at your sample output, it appears you're seeing error stream output which you can easily redirect with `2> $null` or `2> err.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to wrap that command in a call to powershell, for example:

```
powershell -command { write-host "a" }  | out-null
```

or

```
$out = powershell -command { write-host "a" }
```

you won't see the `a` being printed.

But when you do

```
write-host "a" | out-null
```

you will see the `a`

Comment: but will he get the output?

Comment: Having a hard time getting this to work. `$test = powershell -command { write-host "a"; $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{Testprop="Testval"}; $obj }` that doesn't return `$obj`. Well, acutally it does, but it also outputs all the write-host so you will have to dig deep into the array to find the object.

Comment: @Graimer - That's the intention? Make the `write-host` output "pipeable".

Comment: guess I just misunderstood the question. I got the idea that he wanted the output(object) to be stored in a variable while suppressing write-host messages.

Comment: Thanks for this answer... I just tested it, and unfortunately, it doesn't work. Since the new PowerShell session doesn't carry over the imported modules, the cmdlet does not execute. If I import the module, the cmdlet still will not work properly, because the variables called in the command do not exist in the new session.

Answer (score 1):

you could redirect output to a file ?
PS V3 only :

```
#Invalid command:
ping -rrfrfr *> $env:temp\test.txt 
$? # last execution status will be false

ping google.com *>> $env:temp\test.txt 
$?  #true as command is valid

$resu=gc $env:temp\test.txt
$resu
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$move = Move-VM -VM $vmToMigrate -VMHost $destinationHost 2> err.txt
```

This will return normal stdout output to `$move` and errors will be put in a file. If you're not interested in the errors at all then:

```
$move = Move-VM -VM $vmToMigrate -VMHost $destinationHost 2> $null
```

Comment: Really? I don't see this working. As per what OP wants, this should work? `& {write-host "a"} 2> blah.txt`. It still prints a?

Comment: Where is the `Write-Host` in the OP's issue?  Please don't tell me Move-VM is using write-host.

Comment: Seems like it if `$a = Move-VM ...` returns stuff to the console.

Comment: The cmdlet could be using the error stream. Plus Move-VM is a binary cmdlet where you have to go out of your way to use this.Host.UI.Write* which is pretty unusual. And a cursory look at the decompiled Move-VM code in dotPeek reveals nothing but the use of WriteObject and throwing exceptions.  The command appears to be outputting error info (red text followed by error record info) if you follow the link in the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to a variable is how I suppress unwanted output in my scripts. If that fails I always precede my function call with `[void]`, like so:

```
[void]Move-VM -VM $vmToMigrate -VMHost $destinationHost
```

Comment: `[void]Get-VM` triggers `Unexpected token 'Get-VM' in expression or statement` with Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Just set the ProgressPreference variable in your script this will not show the progress of the migration and also just use pipe after the command and put out-null
for Eg:

```
Set-Variable ProgressPreference SilentlyContinue
Move-VM -VM $vm -Destination $destination_srv >$null or out-null
```

Thanks